# How to render check boxes within a render UI in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am new to shiny and was wondering if the following is possible, I have not found any examples online on stackoverflow or any github issues either.

I have the following shiny dashboard seen below - I have 2 dataframes that are built into the app - for now these are just test dataframes, one called `nodes_data_1` and one called `edges_data_1`.

The reason I want it in a `renderUI` is because I want it to use the reactive `node_data_reactive()` - as this may change in future making it easier for me.

The dataframe called `nodes_data_1` is the one of importance here - I want a way so that when a user clicks on the sidebar radio button "Food Type" - 
tab panels will be created based on the unique values in the `nodes_data_1$Food` column - which has 5 values - so there would be 5 separate tab panels all sitting within this large tab box.

Then after doing this, within each tab panel, checkboxes would be rendered which correspond to the values in the `nodes_data_1$Product_name` which sit in the `nodes_data_1$Food category`.

So for example the app will look something like this:

[Outcome I want in the Shiny Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVc18.png)

Here you can see in the dashboard - that when I am on the "Edibles" Tab Panel - the available options to select are those in the data that are in the "Edibles" category for Food

Please see the code below - I do not know how to create such a thing - any ideas are welcome - new to shiny so hope this is possible!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard) 
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "My Dashboard",
  titleWidth = 500
)

siderbar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(

    # Add buttons to choose the way you want to select your data
    radioButtons("select_by", "Select by:",
                 c("Food Type" = "Food",
                   "Gym Type" = "Gym",
                   "TV show" = "TV"))

  )   

)

body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(
      uiOutput("Output_panel")

  ), 
   tabBox(title = "RESULTS", width = 12, 
      tabPanel("Visualisation", 
                 width = 12, 
                height = 800
              )


    )
  ) 

ui <- dashboardPage(header, siderbar, body, skin = "purple")


server <- function(input, output, session) {

nodes_data_1 <- data.frame(id = 1:15, 
                           Food = as.character(c("Edibles", "Fried", "Home Cooked", "packaged", "vending machine")), 
                           Product_name = as.character(c("Bacon", "Cheese", "eggs", "chips", "beans", "oast", "oats and beans", "fried beans", "chickpeas", "broad beans", "garbanzo", "oat bars", "dog meat", "cat food", "horse meat")),
                           Gym_type = as.character(paste("Gym", 1:15)), TV = 
                             sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE))

# build a edges dataframe

edges_data_1 <- data.frame(from = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1,
                    to = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1)


# create reactive of nodes 

  nodes_data_reactive <- reactive({
   nodes_data_1


  }) # end of reactive
  # create reacive of edges 

  edges_data_reactive <- reactive({

  edges_data_1

  }) # end of reactive



  # The output panel differs depending on the how the data is selected 
  # so it needs to be in the server section, not the UI section and created
  # with renderUI as it is reactive
  output$Output_panel <- renderUI({

    # When selecting by workstream and issues:
    if(input$select_by == "Food") {

      box(title = "Output PANEL", 
          collapsible = TRUE, 
          width = 12,

                 do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id='t',lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
        food <- unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)

        tabPanel(food[i], 
                 checkboxGroupInput(paste0("checkboxfood", i), 
                                    label = NULL, 
                                    choices = nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
                                      filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
                                      select(Product_name) %>%
                                      unlist(use.names = FALSE)))
              } #end of function
            ) # end of lapply
         ) # end of combine c 
      ), # end of tab panel 


      # add a checkbox that is a select all 



   actionButton(inputId = "selectall", label = "Select All Above/Deselect") 







 ) # end of Tab box



    # When selecting by the strength of links connected to the issues:  
    } else if(input$select_by == "Gym") {
       box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("select_gyms", "Select gyms you want to display", choices = unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Gym_type)
                             ,
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

    } else if(input$select_by == "TV") {
       box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("select_tvs", 
                             "Select the tv shows you want to see",choices = sort(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$TV)),
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

  }  # end of else if

  }) # end of renderUI



} # end of server


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard) 
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "My Dashboard",
  titleWidth = 500
)

siderbar <- dashboardSidebar(

  sidebarMenu(

    # Add buttons to choose the way you want to select your data
    radioButtons("select_by", "Select by:",
                 c("Food Type" = "Food",
                   "Gym Type" = "Gym",
                   "TV show" = "TV"))

  )   

)

body <- dashboardBody(

  fluidRow(
    uiOutput("Output_panel")

  ), 
  tabBox(title = "RESULTS", width = 12, 
         tabPanel("Visualisation", 
                  width = 12, 
                  height = 800
         )


  )
) 

ui <- dashboardPage(header, siderbar, body, skin = "purple")


server <- function(input, output, session){

  nodes_data_1 <- data.frame(id = 1:15, 
                             Food = as.character(c("Edibles", "Fried", "Home Cooked", "packaged", "vending machine")), 
                             Product_name = as.character(c("Bacon", "Cheese", "eggs", "chips", "beans", "oast", "oats and beans", "fried beans", "chickpeas", "broad beans", "garbanzo", "oat bars", "dog meat", "cat food", "horse meat")),
                             Gym_type = as.character(paste("Gym", 1:15)), TV = 
                               sample(LETTERS[1:3], 15, replace = TRUE))

  # build a edges dataframe

  edges_data_1 <- data.frame(from = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1,
                             to = trunc(runif(15)*(15-1))+1)


  # create reactive of nodes 

  nodes_data_reactive <- reactive({
    nodes_data_1


  }) # end of reactive
  # create reacive of edges 

  edges_data_reactive <- reactive({

    edges_data_1

  }) # end of reactive



  # The output panel differs depending on the how the data is selected 
  # so it needs to be in the server section, not the UI section and created
  # with renderUI as it is reactive
  output$Output_panel <- renderUI({

    # When selecting by workstream and issues:
    if(input$select_by == "Food") {

      box(title = "Output PANEL", 
          collapsible = TRUE, 
          width = 12,

          do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id='t',lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
            food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))

            tabPanel(food[i], 
                     checkboxGroupInput(paste0("checkboxfood_", i), 
                                        label = NULL, 
                                        choices = nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
                                          filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
                                          select(Product_name) %>%
                                          unlist(use.names = FALSE)),
                     checkboxInput(paste0("all_", i), "Select all", value = TRUE)
          )
          })))

      ) # end of Tab box



      # When selecting by the strength of links connected to the issues:  
    } else if(input$select_by == "Gym") {
      box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("select_gyms", "Select gyms you want to display", choices = unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Gym_type)
                             ,
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

    } else if(input$select_by == "TV") {
      box(title = "Output PANEL", collapsible = TRUE, width = 12,
          checkboxGroupInput("select_tvs", 
                             "Select the tv shows you want to see",choices = sort(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$TV)),
                             selected = NULL,
                             inline = FALSE
          )# end of checkboxGroupInput
      ) # end of box  

    }  # end of else if

  }) # end of renderUI

  observe({
    lapply(1:length(unique(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)), function(i) {
      food <- unique(sort(as.character(nodes_data_reactive()$Food)))
      product_choices <- nodes_data_reactive() %>% 
        filter(Food == food[i]) %>%
        select(Product_name) %>%
        unlist(use.names = FALSE)

      if(!is.null(input[[paste0("all_", i)]])){
        if(input[[paste0("all_", i)]] == TRUE) {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choices = product_choices,
                                   selected = product_choices)
        } else {
          updateCheckboxGroupInput(session,
                                   paste0("checkboxfood_", i), 
                                   label = NULL, 
                                   choices =product_choices)
        }
      }
    })
  })

} # end of server


# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks thats okay - but how can i add a select all button on each tab? that would select all of the checkboxes within that tab panel only?

Comment: So this is the select all button that would fit on every single tab panel and when a user selects it - it will select only those checkboxes in that specific panel and not the other tab panels - it can be an action link or radio button or anything!!!!

Comment: I suppose the simplest way to do it would be with an update `updateCheckboxGroupInput`. I've edited my answer to show one example of how it could work

Comment: Thanks Galina for the help, i was hoping that there would be a way so that when the app loads, every box is not "checked" within each Tab Panel - and only through the use of the select all button would it work on that tab Panel - any thoughts on how this could be done - great work so far for helping me though!

Comment: Really would be keen on getting that select all button to not select everything on the first instance

Comment: Change the `checkboxInput(paste0("all_", i), "Select all", value = TRUE)` from `TRUE` to `FALSE`

Comment: Thank you very much for the help - really helpful!

Comment: if that is what you needed, can you please accept the answer?

Comment: Hi - i actually have updated the code - i want to know how i can use ChoiceNames and Choice Values instead - so that the checkboxes appear as the choiceNames but the underlying choice values are what is being selected, so my choiceNames will be the Product Names but my choiceValues will be the Price values in the Price Column, Any ideas?